# Cannot match any routes error in angular 4 application when it contains special characters

Tags: angular

In my angular application a route may contains `(` `)` `#` `%` `&` `=` , But when it contains any on these I get this error.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:
```

How to encode the route?

Answer (score 0):

You can hard-code your urls with [encoded character](http://www.cheat-sheets.org/sites/html.su/urlencoding.html) replacements.

```
const path = 'catalog%2810%29'; // this is catalog(20)
```

Or encode the url using [encodeURI](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp) function

```
const path = encodeURI('home(100)');
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-cfwnue

The Home link path is created using the `encodeURI` function and the catalog link path is created using hard-coded encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [URI encoding](https://www.greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc3986.pdf) which is the standard way to encode special characters to make them available in your routes.

JavaScript provides the functions [encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) and [decodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI) for this purpose.

Comment: this document has 48 pages, on which page the solution is?

Comment: Beginning with Chapter 2 "Characters" (page 9) would be a good starting point to understand which characters are reserved and which not. Section 2.4 "When to Code or Decode" is also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In order to allow these in the url, defined a custom URL serializer :

```
import { DefaultUrlSerializer, UrlSerializer, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';

export default class CustomUrlSerializer implements UrlSerializer {
    private _defaultUrlSerializer: DefaultUrlSerializer = new DefaultUrlSerializer();

    parse(url: string): UrlTree {
       // Encode parentheses
       url = url.replace(/\(/g, '%28').replace(/\)/g, '%29');
       // Use the default serializer.
       return this._defaultUrlSerializer.parse(url)
    }

    serialize(tree: UrlTree): string {
       return this._defaultUrlSerializer.serialize(tree).replace(/%28/g, '(').replace(/%29/g, ')');
    }
}
```

Included CustomUrlSerializer in my providers array (within AppModule):

```
providers: [
    { provide: UrlSerializer, useClass: CustomUrlSerializer },
    ...
]
```

Comment: I have route like `component/some value/other value/last value` , if I use this, it will consider all the values as a single value by enconding every `/` .

Comment: Thank you so much this code is working for `(` and `)` . but not working for other special characters as I mentioned in the question.